# How to perform the following svn merge?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I have the following scenario.

Branch 1 contains a New project with out any trunk copy. 
Branch 2 created from branch 1 at revision 46079
Branch 3 created from branch 1 at revision 46114
Project created on trunk by svn copying code from branch 3 at revision 46294

There were some changes that are done both in branch 2 and trunk.

Now I am trying to copy changes that I did from branch 2 to the trunk. 
I am using windows tortoise svn. Could somebody please help me how to do this merge so that trunk will preserve the history from branch 2.

Thanks in advance.

[image: SVN merger issue]

Comment: Branch 1 was created for creating a monolithic project. Then after its completion branch 2 was created to separate core features to a library. Branch 3 was used to carry on some testing on the build root and doesn't contain any major modifications. Right now trunk builds the monolithic project, I want to copy the changes from branch2 to trunk so that it builds non-monolithic project. In fact branch 1 has only change that went between revision 46079 and 46114 that contains implementing review comments. I manually edited branch 2 to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your SVN version support merge tracking, what is missing in your trunk on the moment when you decide to do the merge is changes implemented in br2 since revision 46079.
I suggest you to do 'Merge a range of revisions' operation in Tortoise. As 'url to merge from' you should use br2, 'revision range to merge' you may leave blank, because using merge tracking SVN will automatically determine that differences of br2 and trunk are starting from rev. 46079. Also, working copy where you do merge to must contain your trunk which is up to date and with all changes committed.
Please invoke 'Test Merge' first to validate your results. There must be no Tree Conflicts..